# Javascript adding class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So, I have this if statement and I want to add a class to an element I've added it in my if statement but it doesn't add the class.

```
     $(".project").click(function(){
        if ($(".project-expand",this).is(':visible')) {
          $(".project-expand",this).hide();
        } else if ($(".project-expand",this).is(':hidden')) {
          $(".project-expand",this).show();
          $(".project",this).addClass('item-dropped');
        }
     });
```

Comment: Can you post the corresponding  markup (HTML)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line seems wrong to me

`$(".project",this).addClass('item-dropped');`

You are passing `this` which already should be the `.project` element you clicked as a context for your selector. Unless you have a nested `.project` I don't think jQuery will be able to find the element you are looking for

Replace that line with `$(this).addClass('item-dropped');`